# How to make user defined classes in web2py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, web2py-modules

I am trying to make a class within a module, import that module file in my controller, and then reference the class that is defined within that module, but I keep getting a message that reads `NameError("name 'self' is not defined")`

Here is my code in my created module:

```
from gluon import *

class device_info(object):

    self.info = {}

    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info
        return
    def setInfo(info):
        self.info = info
        return
    def getInfo():
        return self.info`
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how it can be resolved? I was under the impression that user-defined classes were supported in web2py.

Comment: put `self.info = {}` into `__init__`. Don't think of `self` as some magical keyword, its just another argument, its it is undefined outside of a method which receives it as input (such as `__init__`)

Comment: wow... thanks @jphollowed

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python and started on Java. I guess I assumed `self` was Python's version of `this` @jphollowed

Comment: It is similar to `this`, but it must be used more explicitly in python, and all functions in a class must take `self` as their first argument. I'll elaborate in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, just move `self.info = {}` into `__init__()`.

`__init__()` is essentially a constructor that you are familiar with from java. It *initializes* an instance object of that class when called. I haven't used Java in some time, but I don't think you should be be declaring class variables outside of your constructor there either.

`self` is an argument that all methods within a class in python must receive as their first argument. So your getters and setters are also not going to work if you try them; they must be:

`def setInfo(self, info)` and `def getInfo(self)`

When you create an object, like this:

`device1 = device_info()`

it calls `__init()__`, passing `device1` as `self`. Then, whenever you use that object, such as

`device1.setInfo(newInfo)`, you can think of the method in the class' context being called as `setInfo(device1, newInfo)`, since `device1` is `self`, or the current instance of the `device_info` object in use.

You also don't need the `object` argument at the class definition. What do you expect that to do?

---

**Edit**: Actually, don't move `self.info = {}` into `__init__()`, just get rid of it. You already have `self.info = info` in `__init__()`. You don't need to initialize variables like that in Python like you do in Java. Creating an empty `dict` and then setting it to another `dict` without any use is redundant.

Comment: In Python, __new__() is a constructor, not __init__().

Comment: @Waqas Correct, but I said _essentially_ a constructor. No need to confuse him if he is coming from Java and trying to draw parallels, `__init__()` will do exactly as you expect it to, and you usually will not write your own `__new__()`.